# How to split data where the Input has size 841

Tags: r, split, training-data

I am trying to split my data into test and train (data = all.traits), however, this error message shows up every time:

```
Error: Must subset rows with a valid subscript vector.
ℹ Logical subscripts must match the size of the indexed input.
x Input has size 841 but subscript `split_data == 0` has size 840.
```

I have 841 rows but the split always sees the data as a total of 840 so the data won't split

I tried this code:

```
split1\<- sample(c(rep(0, 0.7 \* nrow(all.traits)), rep(1, 0.3 \* nrow(all.traits))))
split1
table(split1)
train \<- all.traits\[split1 == 0, \]
test \<- all.traits\[split1== 1, \]
```

I also found on here that adding `round()` should help, but I get the same error message:

```
 set.seed(1234)
    split_data_frame <- sample(c(rep(0, round(0.7 * nrow(all.traits))), rep(1, round(0.3 * nrow(all.traits)))))
    
    table(split_data_frame)
    
    train <- all.traits[split_data == 0, ]
    test <- all.traits[split_data == 1, ]
```

Comment: are you restricted to base R? Otherwise try to apply https://rsample.tidymodels.org/reference/initial_split.html

Answer (score 0):

Probably a rounding error. If you're restricted to base R functionality (see @Stephan 's suggestion) you could try:

```
zero_count <- round(0.7 * nrow(all.traits))
sample(c(rep(0, zero_count), rep(1, nrow(all.traits)-zero_count)))
```

... which makes sure that zeros and ones total `nrow`